# Change screen brightness with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to change the screen brightness via cmd
I used the following

```
POWERCFG -SETDCVALUEINDEX <SCHEME_GUID> <SUBGROUP_GUID> <SETTING_GUID> value
```

```
powercfg /q | findstr Scheme

Power Scheme GUID: 82562851-6b61-478e-a6fa-caf030f0221b  (High Performance)
```

and

```
powercfg /q | findstr Display
Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)
   Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb  (Display brightness)
```

This is what i am entering

```
powercfg -SetDcValueIndex 82562851-6b61-478e-a6fa-caf030f0221b 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb 50
```

What am i doing wrong?

I was expecting to change the screen brightness to 50%

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem:

PowerShell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,YourBrightnessLevel)

YourBrightnessLevel is the number you want to set the brightness to.